# Unable to copy a table into a new table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to clone a table schema and data into a new table, this is what I'm doing:

`SELECT * INTO 'ECO7053__settings' FROM base__settings`

I keep getting the `Undeclared Variable` error

**EDIT**: Also to complete the questions, is this the correct approach? I need to store data for different users; is it better to add an uID field on my tables and filter by that or rather what I'm trying to do, and have different tables one for each user with a prefix? In the example the uID would be 7053 what would be the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Do not use single quotes for identifiers in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the ' is actually a ` just I could not write it here

Comment: Use `CREATE TABLE ECO7053__settings AS SELECT * FROM base__settings;` ?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson works but doesn't copy the PK and AI of the first field, turned it into a regular INT

Comment: i think you can use this link. There is no single sql to copy structure + data. Link - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/copy-complete-structure-of-a-table

Comment: @S.Redrum ou may have to do it in two steps: `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ....;` and then `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ECO7053__settings LIKE base__settings;
```

to copy the table schema and indices. Then

```sql
INSERT INTO ECO7053__settings SELECT * FROM base__settings;
```

to copy the data.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. Did not know about the `CREATE TABLE ..LIKE`. A very elegant solution

Comment: would this be a good approach considering what in my edit?

Comment: I for one would not create a table for each user due to scalability issues, but that is a different question from the one you originally asked.

Comment: Almost certainly better to create a single table with a UID column than to create distinct tables. You'd need a specialized case to warrant the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE base__settings
```

Copy the create statement and change `base__settings` into `ECO7053__settings` (do a search and replace)

Then run

```
INSERT INTO ECO7053__settings
SELECT * FROM base__settings
```